# Increment and decrements on button click using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I want when I click on increment button than points will increase. I do this in server side code but it increment after reloading page. I want it to do this without reloading page using ajax and jquery 
here is my code

Deals.cs

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string HOT(int DealPoints,int dealId)
{
    DealPoints++;
    int DealId = dealId;
    int Points = DealPoints;

    string retDeal = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FYP_Wish"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IncrementDeals", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DealPoints", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Points;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DealId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DealId;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            return "true";
        }
        con.Close();
        return retDeal;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is you client-side code? have you already tried something?

Comment: $(function () {
        $("[id*=HotButton]").bind("click", function () {
            var Deal = {};
            Deal.DealPoints = $("[id*=<%#Eval("DealPoints") %>]").val();
            Deal.DealId = $("[id*=<%#Eval("DealId") %>]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Deals.aspx/HOT",
                data: '{DealPoints: ' + JSON.stringify(DealPoints) + ',DealId: ' + JSON.stringify(DealId) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                d

Comment: here is but when i click onbutton its not working

Comment: Edit your question and add your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#btn1").click(function(e) { //btn1 is button id
    var o = $(this).val();
    o++;
    $(this).val(o);
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)